Laravel can't find my table when testing using an alternate connection
I have an application in Laravel that requires the use of different connections. My model User requires a regular "mysql" connection, while the related model, let's call it "HBSPT_COMPANIES" requires a "snowflake" connection. I don't have any issues when interacting with those two connections until testing. Regarding migrations I have the mysql ones but I do not have migrations for the snowflake connection, since that's sorta an external data source.
When testing I have my regular mysql connection substituted by a simple sqlite connection in memory, I use the RefreshDatabase trait to run the migrations for mysql connections but I have a snowflake_testing.sqlite file that's supposed to be used instead of the snowflake connection with some testing data.
My issue is that when trying to grab the data in my tests I get:
SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1 no such table: HBSPT_COMPANIES (Connection: snowflake_testing, SQL: select * from "HBSPT_COMPANIES" where "name" = TEST_STUDENT)
I have my .env.testing like this:
...
APP_ENV=testing

DB_CONNECTION=sqlite
DB_DATABASE=:memory:

SNOWFLAKE_DB_CONNECTION=snowflake_testing
SNOWFLAKE_DB_DATABASE=/path/to/file/database/snowflake_testing.sqlite
...

And in my config/database.php added the following configuration
'snowflake_testing' => [
    'driver' => 'sqlite',
    'database' => env('SNOWFLAKE_DB_DATABASE'),
    'prefix' => '',
    'foreign_key_constraints' => env('DB_FOREIGN_KEYS', true),
],

This is my test:
use Tests\TestCase;


class ReportPolicyTest extends TestCase
{

    use RefreshDatabase;

    #[Test]
    public function it_allows_a_student_to_see_the_student_report(): void
    {

        $activeSchool = HubspotCompany::query()
            ->where('name', 'TEST_STUDENT')->get();

This is my HubspotCompany model:
class HubspotCompany extends Model
{

    use HasFactory;
    .
    .
    .
    protected $primaryKey = 'HS_OBJECT_ID';

    public $incrementing = false;

    protected $table = 'HBSPT_COMPANIES';


    public function __construct(array $attributes = array())
    {

        parent::__construct($attributes);

        $connection = config('app.env') !== 'testing' ? 'snowflake' : 'snowflake_testing';

        $this->setConnection($connection);

    }

Unfortunately, every resource in Google that I found talks about how to set a sqlite as a primary database connection that will be rewritten using the RefreshDatabase trait, I couldn't find anything regarding already generated dummy data for phpunit and Laravel
Obviously I tried checking that my snowflake_testing.sqlite has indeed the table and some data in it using this query:
select *
from HBSPT_COMPANIES
where "name" = "TEST_STUDENT" limit 1

And I got the expected data:

I tried playing around with the naming and the connection but it seems that that is already in order.

In your super simple test, if you remove RefreshDatabase, so migrate:fresh is not run, do you get data back?

Well, the test is more complicated, I just shared until the last line where it breaks. And no, commenting the trait still gives me the same error

You also have to set environnement variable value in phpunit.xml and then clear the cache.
<server name="APP_ENV" value="testing"/>

By the way, I find it weird to add some logic in your Eloquent models to pick the right connection, I think you can delete those parts.
